# Jquery select all objects with a particular attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to select all elements on my page that have a particular attribute.

For example, I have an attribute called `"tip"` I add `tip="...whatever..."` to a lot of my html tags. I would like to be able to select all html tags that have this attribute.

NOT all html tags that have that attribute equal to a particular value. Just have the attribute AT ALL; REGARDLESS of value.

I apologize for my confusing wording and inadiquite vocabulary in my question. I have now updated the question to use proper wording.

Thanks!

Comment: I currently had a class called "tip" to each of these objects, but it's such a hassle to do both the class and the value...

Comment: So you have elements with an attribute of "tip"?  Like `<a href="foo.html" tip="blah">` and `<img src="foo.png" tip="blahblah" />` ?

Comment: @charliegriefer - yes sorry i wasn't more clear

Comment: no worries.  You might want to update the question tho, to replace "value" with "attribute", as that is actually what you're asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( '[tip]' )
```

attributeHas selector

"Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute, with any value."

See http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/

Answer (score 1):

## Update:

---

You can do like this:

```
$('[tip="something"]')
```

You can replace `something` with whatever your string is.

---

You can use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) filter selector like this:

```
$('p:contains("tip")').color('red', 'green');
```

That for example will select all paragraphs that have `tip` keyword in their value/html.

Comment: can I use this without the p? $("contains('tip')")?

Comment: @kralco626: I don't think so and even so it will be expensively slow.

Comment: so maybe charlie's solution is better for large ammounts of objects?

Comment: @kralco626: Sure if that works for you. We are not sure what exactly you mean by object. Whether you want to search for a custom tag, custom attribute or some text inside a tag.

Comment: sorry. once again my poor verbage. What is this called `<div id="something" class="something" tip="something"></div>` or this `<table></table>` or this `<p></p>` or this `<input/>` or this `<td></td>`? What are all of those called? I originate a java programmer, so I call them objects. What are this called in this environment?

Comment: @kralco626: They are html tags wrapped in `<>`. See my updated answer because now I understand it after seeing your code.

Comment: Thanks, so I should replace the word `"object"` in my question with `"html tages"`

Comment: I updated my question. I think it should be more understandable now.

Comment: @kralco626: I have already updated my answer as I understood now, you can check my answer again.

Comment: not quite what I want. I want all html tags that contain that attribute, REGARDLESS of value. (I updated my question to make this more clear)

Comment: @kralco626: In that case you can simply do: `$('[tip]')`

Comment: which is why I was asking what you thought about charlie's solution in my third comment. You has said `:contains("tip")` was expencive. I was wondering if his solution was any less expencive.

Comment: @kralco626: Ok right and by the time your question wasn't clear :)

Answer (score 0):

If they are all attributes - e.g. tip="foo" then you can use the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) as shown below:

```
jQuery('[attribute="value"]')
```

So in your case:

```
$('div[tip="foo"]')
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/EDdvt/)